# Tem como usar o servidor embutido do php sem adicionar o php no Path?

Tags: php, servidor, path

Tem como usar o servidor embutido do php sem adicionar o php no Path de variáveis ambientes do windows?

Comment: Localize aonde está o binário `php.exe` e digite seu caminho absoluto no prompt de comando ou no PowerShell. Por exemplo: `C:\CaminhoDoDiretorioPhp\php.exe -S localhot:8080 -t C:\CaminhoDoDiretorioDoMeuProjeto`, onde a opção `-t` indica o diretório raiz do seu projeto PHP.

Comment: Deu certinho! Valeu! Abraço.